How to add extra attributes to PyTorch labels?
I want to train NNs for classification with PyTorch and let's say that I have data similar to here. 
HW1, HW2 midterms, final, merits are features for training. Results are the actual class label which I want to predict. After that, I want to calculate pass/fail accuracy grouped by major or mapped back to ID.
So, how can I add those extra attributes and hide them (along with labels) for later use?
Maybe it doesn't have to be done this way, but how can I map back to ID and major for further calculation?
This is how I'd read my data (not read directly from folders assigned labels)
import torch
import numpy as np
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, DataLoader

my_x = [np.array([[1.0,2],[3,4]]), np.array([[5.,6],[7,8]]), np.array([[9.,2],[0,7]])] # a list of numpy arrays
my_y = [np.array([4.]), np.array([2.]), np.array([6.])] # another list of numpy arrays (targets)

tensor_x = torch.Tensor(my_x) # transform to torch tensor
tensor_y = torch.Tensor(my_y)

my_dataset = TensorDataset(tensor_x,tensor_y) # create your datset
my_dataloader = DataLoader(my_dataset) # create your dataloader

Thx.
